# Dijkstra's Algorithm for simchi-levi berman's network

Tags: shortest-path, dijkstra

Does anyone have the shortest paths for this network? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ds4B.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Where is this image taken from? What have you tried so far to compute the shortest paths?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.